# Python 3 : Converting UTF-8 unicode Hindi Literal to Unicode

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, hindi

I have a string of UTF-8 literals

'\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2' which covnverts to

ही बोल in Hindi. I am unable convert `string a` to bytes

```
a = '\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2'
#convert a to bytes
#also tried a = bytes(a,'utf-8')
a = a.encode('utf-8')
s = str(a,'utf-8')
```

> The string is converted to bytes but contains wrong unicode literals

**RESULT** : `b'\xc3\xa0\xc2\xa4\xc2\xb9\xc3\xa0\xc2\xa5\xc2\x80 \xc3\xa0\xc2\xa4\xc2\xac\xc3\xa0\xc2\xa5\xc2\x8b\xc3\xa0\xc2\xa4\xc2\xb2'` which prints - `à¤¹à¥ à¤¬à¥à¤²`

**EXPECTED** : It should be `b'\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80\xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2` which will be ही बोल

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You have bytes (a UTF-8 encoded string). What do you want to do with it? Is `b'\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2'.decode('utf8')` what you are looking for?

Comment: It is wrong bytes string, It should be b'\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2

Comment: So your starting point is the string "ही बोल"? If so you might be looking for `'ही बोल'.encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: 'ही बोल is not starting point. This is  '\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2'  ही बोल is end expected result

Comment: I don't get it. Your starting point and your result seems to be the same. If so, no processing is needed. It might be helpful if you provided the bigger context: Where does the data come from and in what format? Where does need to go and in what format?

Comment: I get this '\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2' and want to get ही बोल

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *raw-unicode-escape* codec to encode the string as bytes, then you can decode as UTF-8.

```
>>> s = '\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2'
>>> s.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
'ही बोल'
```

This is something of a workaround; the ideal solution would be to prevent the source of the data stringifying the original bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Your original string was likely decoded as `latin1`.  Decode it as UTF-8 instead if possible, but if received messed up you can reverse it by encoding as `latin1` again and decoding correctly as UTF-8:

```
>>> s = '\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2'
>>> s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'ही बोल'
```

Note that `latin1` encoding matches the first 256 Unicode code points, so `U+00E0` (`'\xe0'` in a Python 3 `str` object) becomes byte E0h (`b'\xe0'` in a Python 3 `bytes` object).  It's a 1:1 mapping between U+0000-U+00FF and bytes 00h-FFh.

Answer (score -1):

After using above code ,You are still facing error to encode your string.
Use *sys* **module** to encode the string .

- Use this code -

- ```
     import sys
  ```
- ```
     sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf8',errors='backslashreplace')
  ```
- ```
     s='\xe0\xa4\xb9\xe0\xa5\x80 \xe0\xa4\xac\xe0\xa5\x8b\xe0\xa4\xb2'
  ```
- ```
     print(s.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8'))
  ```
- ```
     or print(txt.encode().decode())
  ```